# Communication 64-bit Matlab and 32-bit Labview

Tags: matlab, com, 32bit-64bit, labview

I am attempting to call a 32 bit DLL from 64 bit Matlab. I have chosen to use
Labview, 32 bit and it's DLL import wizard and calling Labview through ActiveX.
I am forced to follow this path as a use a 32-bit DLL supplied by a instrument vendor.

If I have Labview 64-bit installed, i can use the Matlab line 
`e=actxserver('LabVIEW.Application');` 
, it loads fine

If I have (only) Labview 32-bit installed, the line 
`e=actxserver('LabVIEW.Application');` 
fails with the message "Server Creation Failed: The system cannot find the file specified."

However, if I start the 32 bit Labview executable so that it is running, the matlab line `e=actxserver('LabVIEW.Application');` works fine, and I can invoke a VI , set in parameters, 
run the VI from Matlab and so forth.

So, Matlab cannot initiate Labview, but it can "connect to" a currently running Labview instance.
Could someone understand and explain what is happening?

Kind regards, 
Lars Granlöf

Comment: OK, just to get this straight: you want to call a DLL in LabVIEW and call LabVIEW from MATLAB to do that, right? (This obviously leads to the question of *why*?^^)

Comment: is it an option to call the DLL in MATLAB directly (via `mex`) or to call everything from LavVIEW? (There is a MATLAB node, which provides full MATLAB-functionality because it opens MATLAB in the background)

Comment: Your assumption is right, and your question is justified. 
The DLL handles communication with an instrument that we use in our work,
it is a 32-bit DLL and the supplier has no plans to issue a 64-bit version.
Since Matlab has abandoned 64-bit software since version R2015b, I have to
solve the problem communicating Matlab 64-bit -- DLL 32 bit.
I tried the DLLwrapper software but failed, maybe it could have worked if I
had more experience with similar things, two of my strengths are Matlab and Labview,
so i went that way and am almost at a working solution.

Comment: As far as I have found out, calling a 32-bit DLL directly from 64-bit matlab is not possible, a suggested bridge is the COM system, which I use to communicate 
Matlab 64 bit -- Labview 32 bit.
Thank you for taking the time to be considerate.

Comment: While LabVIEW definitely can handle this issue (calling 64bit MATLAB in the background from a 32-bit LabVIEW), it might also do the communication to the instrument without the wrapper DLL.  MATLAB can still compile 32bit DLLs (at least MATLAB Coder + command line call of a 32bit compiler), I am just not sure if it can compile them to a `mex` function. sorry

Answer (score 1):

Verify that the LocalServer key in the Windows Registry is not pointing to the 64bit version of LabVIEW but to the 32bit version, you can find the key here: Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\<*GUID*>

Search "LabVIEW.Application" in the  windows registry to find the Global Unique Identifier, it looks similar to this {XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}

These are the values in my PC:

LocalServer: C:\Program Files (x86)\National Instruments\LabVIEW 2018\LabVIEW.exe /Automation

LocalServer32: C:\Program Files (x86)\National Instruments\LabVIEW 2018\LabVIEW.exe /Automation

ProgID: LabVIEW.Application.8

VersionIndependentProgID: LabVIEW.Application